# SMPP: Setting message_id for submit_sm

Tags: java, python, smpp, jsmpp

Please is it possible to set The unique message identifier, that will later be returned in the DLR for reference purpose.

**Let me explain my current process below:**

My approach is we send a message to the smsc gateway we get an id from smsc, we save this id and when DLR comes we match the id from the dlr to the id we previously save (because we push million of messages for a short period this approach isn't optimal for us, the back and forth to the database).

what I will like to acheive is if there is a way we can add a parameter to the submit message to smsc and retrieve this id when the dlr comes back.

I am using https://github.com/podshumok/python-smpplib for python and https://github.com/uudashr/jsmpp for java

**EDIT**

Below is my PDU for Submit SM

```
{'ms_msg_wait_facilities': None, 'priority_flag': None, 'language_indicator': None, 'its_reply_type': None, '_sequence': 2, 'registered_delivery': True, 'schedule_delivery_time': None, 'sm_default_msg_id': None, 'callback_num_pres_ind': None, 'source_subaddress': None, '_length': 70, 'user_response_code': None, 'sar_msg_ref_num': None, 'short_message': 'Lets Test MT\n', 'privacy_indicator': None, 'user_message_reference': 12, 'sar_total_segments': None, 'dest_addr_ton': 1, 'callback_num': None, 'sar_segment_seqnum': None, '_client': <smpplib.client.Client object at 0x7f2058a6a910>, 'service_type': None, 'source_addr_ton': 1, 'payload_type': None, 'validity_period': None, 'destination_addr': '2349*********', 'esm_class': 0, 'status': 0, 'display_time': None, 'source_addr': '7****', 'replace_if_present_flag': None, 'dest_subaddress': None, 'sm_length': 13, 'data_coding': 0, 'its_session_info': None, 'destination_port': None, 'ussd_service_op': None, 'sms_signal': None, 'protocol_id': 100, 'ms_validity': None, 'source_addr_npi': 1, 'source_addr_subunit': None, 'dest_addr_npi': 1, 'client': <smpplib.client.Client object at 0x7f2058a6a910>, 'command': 'submit_sm', 'more_messages_to_send': None, 'dest_addr_subunit': None, 'source_port': None, 'number_of_messages': None, 'alert_on_message_delivery': None}
```

Below I have the PDU for DeliverSM:

```
{'priority_flag': '0', 'message_state': None, 'language_indicator': None, 'callback_num': None, 'payload_type': None, 'replace_if_present_flag': '0', 'schedule_delivery_time': '', 'sm_default_msg_id': '0', 'source_subaddress': None, 'user_response_code': None, 'sar_total_segments': None, 'short_message': 'id:157de861 sub:001 dlvrd:000 submit date:1705171812 done date:1705171812 stat:UNDELIV err:255', 'privacy_indicator': None, 'user_message_reference': None, 'sar_msg_ref_num': None, 'dest_addr_ton': '1', 'sar_segment_seqnum': None, 'esm_class': '4', '_sequence': 67108866, 'service_type': '', 'source_addr_ton': '1', 'validity_period': '', 'destination_addr': '7****', '_client': <smpplib.client.Client object at 0x7f2058a6a910>, 'status': 0, 'source_addr': '234********', 'registered_delivery': '0', 'dest_subaddress': None, 'message_payload': None, 'sm_length': '94', 'data_coding': '0', 'destination_port': None, 'source_addr_npi': '1', 'protocol_id': '0', 'network_error_code': None, 'its_session_info': None, 'dest_addr_npi': '1', 'length': 145, 'client': <smpplib.client.Client object at 0x7f2058a6a910>, 'command': 'deliver_sm', 'source_port': None, 'receipted_message_id': None}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an optional `user_message_reference` TLV parameter that can be set to your message ID for reference, however, I'd suggest testing first, in case your SMSC doesn't support it.

Comment: Thanks will try it out now

Comment: It seems that your SMSC simply doesn't support this parameter. The SMPP standard doesn't have any other way to put your reference ID in, so I'd ask your SMSC, whether they could support the parameter and if not, then are there any other options - maybe they have some custom solution for this, though it is unlikely.

Comment: thanks so much @pilsetnieks. will have to look for a way around it then. Really appreciate

Comment: Why don't you simply use message_id returned on submit, write it to your database, so upon DR you can match the record (I suggest you match together with the recipient number also provided in DR as sender number)

Answer (score 0):

For my [async SMPP client, naz](https://github.com/komuw/naz); what I did was:

- When it sends a *SUBMIT_SM* request to SMSC, it keeps a record of the *sequence_number* somewhere(in-memmory or database etc)
- Since SMSC always returns that *sequence_number* in *SUBMIT_SM_RESP*; get the *sequnce_number* and look it up from where we had saved it.

That will work for *SUBMIT_SM* & *SUBMIT_SM_RESP*. You will need some other mechanism for relating *SUBMIT_SM* & *DELIVER_SM*. That is where *user_message_reference* comes in.
Unfortunately, some/most SMSCs do not support *user_message_reference*